# refresh markers google maps

Tags: javascript, vb.net, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How do I let my markers automatically change positions with data from aspx.vb. I tried to use an interval but it didn't work because it had still the same  position. I know I have to use ajax but i don't know how it works.

```
    <body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function initMap() 
    {
        var myLatLng = { lat: 50.4720256, lng: 5.7289935 };
        var markers = JSON.parse('<%=ConvertDataTabletoString() %>');




        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), 
        {
            zoom: 8,
            center: myLatLng,
            mapTypeControl: false,
            mapTypeControl: false,
            zoomControl: true,
            zoomControlOptions: 
            {
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_CENTER
            },
            scaleControl: true,
            streetViewControl: false
        });          
    for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) 
    {
        var data = markers[i]
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.Latitude, data.Longitude);


        image = 
        { 
        url: data.Kind + ".png",
        size:new google.maps.Size(32 , 32),
        };

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker(
        {
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            icon: image,
            title: data.RegistrationNbr
        });
    }
}

</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYAPI-WZq_c&signed_in=false&callback=initMap" async defer>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but try to put interval and you should call 's*etPosition*'

Here's a code snippet for 'setPosition':

var new_marker_position = new google.maps.LatLng(53.345735, -6.259548);   marker.setPosition(new_marker_position);

Here's the Official Google Documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference

I hope it will help you.